# IPv6 address problem in `ifreq` struct

Tags: c++, c, sockets, network-programming, ipv6

I am working with the following code:

```
struct sockaddr_in6 *sin;
struct ifreq ifr;
sin = (struct sockaddr_in6 *)&ifr.ifr_addr;
```

`ifr_addr` is of type `struct sockaddr`, which for convenience is reported here under:

```
struct sockaddr {
        sa_family_t     sa_family;      /* address family, AF_xxx       */
        char            sa_data[14];    /* 14 bytes of protocol address */
};
```

How am I supposed to put an IPv6 address (via `sin->sin6_addr.s6_addr`) in the `ifr_addr` field given there are only 14 bytes available?

Where am I going wrong?

TIA,
Chris

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fortunately `struct ifreq` is declared to contain the addresses in a union at the end of the structure:

```
struct ifreq
  {


    union
      {
 char ifrn_name[16];
      } ifr_ifrn;

    union
      {
 struct sockaddr ifru_addr;
 struct sockaddr ifru_dstaddr;
 struct sockaddr ifru_broadaddr;
 struct sockaddr ifru_netmask;
 struct sockaddr ifru_hwaddr;
 short int ifru_flags;
 int ifru_ivalue;
 int ifru_mtu;
 struct ifmap ifru_map;
 char ifru_slave[16];
 char ifru_newname[16];
 __caddr_t ifru_data;
      } ifr_ifru;
  };
```

Note that the above was the result of `gcc -E` and so all the preprocessor stuff has been expanded. Also note that `ifr_addr` is `#define`d to be `ifr_ifru.ifru_addr`.

This means that technically, you can allocate bytes off the end of the structure to hold the address.

In my opinion, this is extremely sloppy. The union should be declared to hold a value of type `sockaddr_storage` along with everything else. Then the structure size will be big enough to hold any address.

If you wanted to declare your own structure of the right size that you could use pretty easily, just do this:

```
union my_ifreq {
    struct ifreq sys_ifreq;
    struct {
        char name_pad[IFNAMSIZ];
        struct sockaddr_storage addr;
    } padding;
};
```

Then you will have a structure that always has enough storage that you can stuff any valid address in `sys_ifreq.ifr_addr` and have it work.

Comment: Great explanation. Many thanks! I didn't even spot the `ifru_data` field. However, I'm still confused on how to use it. I mean, what I can do is `sin = (struct sockaddr_in6 *)&ifr.padding.addr;`. But, when I pass around the structure, how does the code know that there is an address at that location?

Comment: @Jir: Just do this: `sin = (struct sockaddr_in6 *)(&ifr.sys_ifreq.ifr_addr)`. The `padding` part is just to make sure the union occupies enough space and should not actually be used. Presumably you will set the `sin->sin6_family` field to `AF_INET6`, and this will be enough to let the system know that there's a full IPv6 address there. If you notice, the family field is the same at the beginning of all the different sockaddr types.

Comment: Now I get the whole picture! And that's why you defined `my_ifreq` as a union and not simply as a struct! Thanks for thoroughly explaining the details once again!

Answer (score 0):

The platforms that use `struct sockaddr` inside `struct ifreq` also have an IPv6 friendly version `struct lifreq` that uses `struct sockaddr_storage` instead for example Solaris, other platforms such as Linux and AIX already use the longer structure.

Comment: Hi Steve! I'm coding for Linux kernel 2.6.26, but I have found no trace of `struct lifreq` unfortunately.

Comment: @Jir see my example usage of `ifreq` for IPv6 here: http://code.google.com/p/openpgm/source/browse/trunk/openpgm/pgm/getifaddrs.c